# Changing icon multiple times using onclick using javascript similar to gmail star icon

Tags: javascript

I have an icon image which changes into another image by this code

```
<html>
<script>

function changeImg(thisImg) {
  if(prevImg) {
    prevImg.src=prevSrc;
  }  
  prevImg = thisImg;
  prevSrc = thisImg.src;
  thisImg.src = "flag_green.gif";
}
</script>
<body>
<img alt="" src="flag_blue.gif" id="imgClickAndChange" onclick="changeImg(this)"  />
</body>
```

But I am unable to change it back to the previous image again after clicking the original image . please help. I want it similar like the gmail important star icon feature

Comment: how many images are you cycling? just two images?

Comment: yes sir i Have only 2 images

Answer (score 1):

Why not do it the easy way?

```
function changeImg(thisImg) {
  if(thisImg.src == "flag_green.gif") {
    thisImg.src = "flag_blue.gif";
  } else {
    thisImg.src = "flag_green.gif";
  }
}
```

Comment: still its not coming sir the image is changing but if i click the changed image , then the first image should come

Answer (score 1):

This might work:

```
var c = 0;
var images = ['src-for-first-image.jpg','src-for-second-image.jpg'];
$('.trigger').on('click', function() {
    $('.image').attr('src', images[c % images.length]);
    c++;
});
```

this lets you loop through many images.

Example:
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jonigiuro/kfmP4/)

Comment: Its working in jquery but can you please tell me in javascript?

Comment: I'm sorry, I left my desk to grill on the roof :)
here's a pure js solution:

    var c = 0;
    var images = ['src-for-first-image.jpg','src-for-second-image.jpg'];

    var trigger = document.getElementById('trigger');
    var image = document.getElementById('image');

    trigger.onmousedown = function() {
        image.src = images[c % images.length];
        c++;
    };

here's the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/jonigiuro/kfmP4/2/

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/pUbrv/

```
<script>
    var altImg = "http://ww1.prweb.com/prfiles/2011/10/12/8875514/star_white.jpg";
    var tmpImg = null;
    function changeImg(thisImg) {
      tmpImg = thisImg.src;
      thisImg.src = altImg;
      altImg = tmpImg;
    }
</script>

<body>
<img alt="" src="http://www.gettyicons.com/free-icons/136/stars/png/256/star_gold_256.png" id="imgClickAndChange" onclick="changeImg(this)" />
</body>
```

----------------- EDITED ----------------------

It's probably easier to load both images and toggle the visibility, rather than changing the src of a single img tag.

Try something like this http://jsfiddle.net/qXYGp/:

```
<span onclick="toggleImg(this)">
    <img src="http://ww1.prweb.com/prfiles/2011/10/12/8875514/star_white.jpg" />
    <img src="http://www.gettyicons.com/free-icons/136/stars/png/256/star_gold_256.png" style="display: none"/>
</span>
```

and for JS:

```
toggleImg = function(container) {
    var imgs = container.getElementsByTagName('img');
    for (i in imgs) {
        if (imgs[i].style.display == 'none')
            imgs[i].style.display = 'inline';
        else
            imgs[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

Comment: just replace the urls in altImg and <img src>

Comment: Thank you so much for your help but there is one problem in this , Actually I have muliple rows flag like this, if I click on one flag, the other flags doesnt respond . please help

Comment: so if you click one flag, all other flags should change as well?

Comment: No its not like that, If I am able to click one flag,I should be able to click the other flags as well

Comment: Look at my edited answer. something like this can be done much easier with jQuery, so consider start using it if you'll have more interactions like this :)

Comment: Thank you so much sir , i have one more doubt, how to do it with multiple rows?

Comment: But I am getting the row dynamically and in the above solution I am getting style.display is null or not an object

Comment: by row, are you talking about a <tr>? When you get the row dynamically, why can't you add the span dynamically as well?

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle for what you currently have? I am not sure if I understand your problem correctly